# inherit from 2 already defined classes in java

Tags: java, android, class, inheritance

Im trying to inherit from multiple classes, I have been told I should use interface, but the problem is that these are predefined classes in java, such as example activity class and Fragment class

Help would be appreciated!!

Comment: Java does not support multiple inheritance with classes.

Comment: Cant you use composition ?

Comment: @AmanArora Composition is not the same as multiple inheritance. Java does not allow multiple inheritance. We have interfaces for that reason - where we can implement multiple interfaces. Composition is more of a design pattern approach than OO principle.

Comment: I gave him an alternative

Answer (score 1):

It seems like a contradiction in design, doesn't it ? An `Activity` may contain `Fragment`s. If you make something both an `Activity` and `Fragment`, what are you trying to do ? =)

No, you can never inherit from two classes in Java.

Answer (score 1):

You can only extend from one class in Java. In your case, `FragmentActivity` seems to be the right choice. Otherwise interfaces are the way to go. Fragments and Activities are different creatures in the android lifecycle and can't be treated equal.

Note that you can have instances of however many different classes in your own custom class though. But that class doesn't have to extend anything.

Answer (score 1):

You could inherit from multiple classes in C++ and not Java. You need to rethink your strategy.